# Comparing lists in Python for mastermind

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m trying to make a Mastermind game in python. The idea behind it is that the computer generates a 4 number code between 1 and 6. Then you have so many guesses to figure it out. If you get the right number in the right spot you get an x, if you get the right number in the wrong spot you get an o and if you get nothing right, you don’t receive anything. The code I have now mostly works but there’s one issue. Say the code is [4, 4, 4, 3] and the guess is [4, 3, 3, 2], the output will be [x, o, o, ,] (it should be [x, o, , ,], it reads the 3 twice)

```
import random
length_of_password = (range(4))
number_of_guesses = (range(8))
code = []
# Generates random code
for random_letter in length_of_password:
    code += str((random.randint(1, 6)))
print(code) # Here just for testing
# Takes guesses and compares them to the code
for guesses in number_of_guesses:
    indicator = ""
    guess = list(input("Guess: "))
    if guess == code:
        print("Congratulations, you won!")
        break
    for letter in length_of_password:
        if guess[letter] == code[letter]:
            print("x")
        elif guess[letter] in code:
            print("o")
        else:
            pass
    print(indicator)
```

Also I am trying to return the indicator sorted so all the x’s are first and o’s are second (that way they don’t know which number is in the right spot) bonus points if you can help with that.

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself as code-formatted text, no links, no screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

```py
code=['4','4','4','3']
for guess in range(8):
  result=[]
  guess=list(input("Enter guess\n"))
  if guess==code:
    print('success')
    break
  code_copy=code.copy()
  for i in range(4):
    if guess[i]==code[i]:
      result.append('X')
    elif guess[i] in code_copy:
      result.append('O')
      for j in range(4):
        if code_copy[j]==guess[i]:
          code_copy[j]='7'
          break
    else:
      result.append('')
  print(result)
```

Not the neatest solution, but what I tried was making a copy of the original 'code', and in the `If` clause managing the *right number-wrong spot* condition, change the first find of that number in the copy to a 7. I chose 7 since you mentioned the code has digits in the range 1-6.

Note that in the first if condition we must check against the original code, not the copy.